# Detect in app web browser in ios during scan of qr by the qr widget in ios devices

Tags: ios, iphone, qr-code, user-agent

i want to detect in reactjs when i am in browser and when i am in app web browser so that i can perform action on the that basis

```
const userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
if (userAgent.includes('safari') && !userAgent.includes('chrome') && !userAgent.includes('crios')) {
// It's likely Safari, but may also include Safari web views
if (userAgent.includes('wv') || userAgent.includes('webview')) {
// It's probably a Safari web view
console.log('Running in Safari web view');
} else {
// It's likely the Safari browser
console.log('Running in Safari browser');
}
}



const browser = detect();
setLocalItem('browser', browser.name);



if (navigator.standalone) {
  console.log('Running in standalone web view');
} else {
  console.log('Running in Safari browser');
}
```

i tried the above given approach was not working i was not able to detect in app browser of iphone scanner.